# Is there a way to customize the Active/Inactive title bar in Windows 7 with Aero theme?

Tags: windows-7, appearance

I use the Windows 7 Aero theme with transparency turned off, and window color Twilight.

Occasionally I find myself struggling to tell which window is currently focused, because the active/inactive title bar colors seem to alternate between blue and a lighter blue which are fairly similar. Changing the color scheme does not really help - it makes the bar colors alternate between that color and a lighter version of that same color.

Is there a way to change or control this?

In the Advanced Appearance settings in [Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Personalization\Window Color and Appearance] I have tried fiddling with the Active Title Bar/Inactive Title Bar options. As in Vista, these options seem to only apply to those using the classic windows theme, and is otherwise cheerfully ignored (seems to have been actively discussed elsewhere on the net).

Even more frustrating is that while one can change the font styling, they seem to be bound together.

If this is not possible, I would like to solicit other suggestions that could make active/inactive windows more distinguishable.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can change this out-of-the-box in Windows 7.

You might want to look at [**WindowBlinds 7**](http://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/), which allows for more customizations.

[image]

Although I've not used it with Windows 7, I'm pretty sure it can customize the active and inactive title bars differently.

Comment: +1 I'm fairly certain it's not possible with Aero enabled, aside form 3rd party apps. Most annoying, I have the same issue.